# How do I put a border on the left and right side of my UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview, border, frame

im currently building this game and im having some trouble, at the top of my screen there is a ball that I have buttons to make move left and right, I want them to be stopped at the right and left side of the screens because they just keep going when i hold the button to make them move, I was wondering if there is any way I can set some sort of boundary or border to prevent them from keep moving

Comment: Show the code you're using to move them. Have you tried anything to limit the movement?

Comment: redBall.center = CGPointMake(redBall.center.x - 1, redBall.center.y); this is the code im using to make it move to the left when the button is pressed, i have tried using the MAX method but it did not work @Wain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the following instead of your 'redBall.center' line - it checks to see if the ball's new position is inside the border before it moves it..

```
// some border screen coords
borderLeft = 20;
borderRight = 200;

// move ball left
if (redBall.center.x - 1 > borderLeft) {
    redBall.center = CGPointMake(redBall.center.x - 1, redBall.center.y);
}


// move ball right
if (redBall.center.x + 1 < borderRight) {
    redBall.center = CGPointMake(redBall.center.x + 1, redBall.center.y);
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: it didnt seem to help ;/

Comment: Something is wrong elsewhere in your code then.. Post more of your ball moving code so we can see what it's doing..

Comment: Hey sorry i took a while to respond but when i push down on the button it has a timer with an action pointed to the redball code to make the ball move smoothly like its sliding across the screen do you think maybe that can be the cause?

Comment: Yeah - in your timer code - put the action inside an if statement that checks whether the ball position isn't about to go past the border - just like in the code I gave above..

Comment: Okay thanks very much im going to see if it works when i get home

Comment: can I have a tick then please? ;-)

Comment: im kind of new to this web site where would i go to do that?

Comment: yep that's the one! Glad to be of service :-)